# Phrase that means "untranslated, in its original language"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that will allow me to say things like this:

> Having learned English allowed me to read more books [in their
>   original language].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re nearly there already: **in the original** is probably the most usual wording for this.  Or to be more specific you can say **in the original English**, or whatever other language is in question.

> I found this a bit irritating: if my French is insufficient to allow me to read Proust in the original, why should the editors assume that I can read Racine?  — Stephen Fall, [*www.readingproust.com*](http://www.readingproust.com/fugitive.htm)

Google provides [many](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22tolstoy+in+the+original%22) [more](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22chaucer+in+the+original%22) [examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ibsen+in+the+original%22).